# Error while running virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm newbie in using Ubuntu. To run Windows along with Ubuntu, I am using virtualbox. However, I recently encounter this error message while running virtualbox. Despite my several trials with tips found by googling, I can't figure this problem out. Could you please help me out?

Error message:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows 10.

The device helper structure version has changed.

If you have upgraded VirtualBox recently, please make sure you have terminated all VMs and upgraded any extension packs. If this error persists, try re-installing VirtualBox. (VERR_PDM_DEVHLPR3_VERSION_MISMATCH).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: What is your answer to the question it asks? if you have upgraded....

Answer (score 2):

On your host, visit: [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), look for

> VirtualBox 5.1.16 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack

Download the appropriate extension pack.
Once downloaded, install the extension pack.

Follow these instructions for [Windows Host or Linux Host](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-virtualbox-extension-pack-on-linux-windows/)

Basically, the message above is telling you that a feature/setting which is enabled on the virtual machine requires the extension pack to start.